# display NSDictionary to uilables dynamic view

Tags: ios, iphone

I have to parse  a complicated xml

http://clinicaltrials.gov/show/NCT01423929?displayxml=true

in this xml when I change id NCT01423929 then i got another xml and both of xml tags are not fixed there may be change in number of tag according id.

But I have a an xml schema for above xml

http://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/html/images/info/public.xsd

for parsing i am using XMLConverter and XMLReader both are return me NSDictionary but I don't get that how to dynamic work with  NSDictionary to display  keys on left side UILabel and value for that key on right side UILabel I am attached a screen that

[image: sample screen shot how to i want to arrange dat dynamically]

Please help and sorry for bad english

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple as you parse the data from xml.

Lets say your `Dictionary` name is parseDictionary and it's look something like below..

```
parseDictionary:
{
    "Responsible Party" = "Gilead Sciences";
    "Start Date"        = "September, 2013";
    "Last Updated Date" = "August 20, 2013";
}
```

You have already did that. Now just do the below

```
NSArray *keyArray=[parseDictionary allKeys];
for(NSString *key in keyArray)
{
    [leftLabel setText:key]; //set the key on the leftLabel
    [rightLabel setText:[parseDictionary objectForKey:key]]; //set the value on right label.
}
```

NB:: For each and every loop it'll over right the values so you will get only the `Last Updated Date` and `August 20, 2013`. I am just showing you how to get the key with associated value. I guess you must use `UITableView` to show the data. So there will no problem for you.